# Referential integrity constraint violation for none inheritance relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

I am working on a simple CRUD Spring boot REST app with Database H2 (In-Memory) and Hibernate, There is a many to one relationship between a Car entity and a Manufacturer entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
public class Car {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "manufacturerId")
    @ManyToOne()
    private Manufacturer manufacturer;
 /// 
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "manufacturer")
public class Manufacturer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "manufacturer")
    private Set<Car> cars;

//
}
```

When I delete a manufacturer object that has at least a car related to, it shows this exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["FK3UP36SI6VWEIENGPL21JSRI71: PUBLIC.CAR FOREIGN KEY(MANUFACTURER_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.MANUFACTURER(ID) (1)"; SQL statement:
delete from manufacturer where id=? [23503-197]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:259) ~[spring-orm-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:225) ~[spring-orm-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:540) ~[spring-orm-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:746) ~[spring-tx-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714) ~[spring-tx-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:532) ~[spring-tx-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:304) ~[spring-tx-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy111.deleteById(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.service.manufacturer.DefaultManufacturerService.delete(DefaultManufacturerService.java:66) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.controller.ManufacturerController.deleteManufacturer(ManufacturerController.java:61) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doDelete(FrameworkServlet.java:899) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:667) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:178) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3325) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3582) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:600) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:474) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1436) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:493) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3206) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2412) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:156) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:536) ~[spring-orm-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 72 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK3UP36SI6VWEIENGPL21JSRI71: PUBLIC.CAR FOREIGN KEY(MANUFACTURER_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.MANUFACTURER(ID) (1)"; SQL statement:
delete from manufacturer where id=? [23503-197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRow(ConstraintReferential.java:386) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRowRefTable(ConstraintReferential.java:403) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRow(ConstraintReferential.java:278) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.table.Table.fireConstraints(Table.java:995) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.table.Table.fireAfterRow(Table.java:1013) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.dml.Delete.update(Delete.java:108) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
```

how to fix this?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that there is no constraint on the database level? How your tables are created in H2 database?

Comment: I guess all the tables are generated.
I have this on application.yml
`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "manufacturer", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
private Set<Car> cars;
```

and then all cars related to that manufacturer will be also deleted when the manufacturer gets deleted.

This makes sense if all cars require a manufacturer.
If a car can exist without a manufacturer, then you can use the following code instead (put it into the Manufacturer entity):

```
@PreRemove
private void preRemove() {
   for (Car car: cars) {
      car.setManufacturer(null);
   }
}
```

This way cars which belonged to a now deleted manufacturer will still exist but will have a null manufacturer.
If you don't want to use the @PreRemove annotation you can do the iteration inside it manually in your remove manufacturer service method.

Comment: thank you for this answer, I guess it will work.

but I really want to understand why it throws this error. It supposes to work well, Is not it?

Comment: The error is thrown because hibernate creates foreign keys automatically for all tables generated by it as part of the *ddl-auto=create-drop* process. This means that if at least one car was assigned to a manufacturer, the H2 database will restrict deletion of the manufacturer until all its cars have been explicitly reassigned to another manufacturer or set to no manufacturer (null). This constraint has good intentions, so that you never end up with cars which are assigned to a manufacturer that was deleted (their manufacturerId will never point to a nonexisting manufacturer).